# Job step loop for LoadLeveler job scripts?

Tags: parallel-processing, batch-processing

I'm using LoadLeveler to submit jobs on an IBM/BlueGene architecture. I read the documentation made from IBM and also gave Google a try, but I cannot find how to do the following, which I expect should be there:

One can use the

```
queue
```

keyword to tell LoadLeveler that a new job step is described, so I could do something like

```
first_step
queue
second_step
queue
```

but what I fail to find is a way that does something like

```
loop job_id = 1,10
   do_job_with_given_job_id
end
```

Do I have to write a "normal" shell script that in turn calls a load level script for a bunch of times, or is there some built in loop mechanism? I know that other job managers can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this comes up, we normally just recommend that one writes a shell script which generates the job submission script or scripts; that's what I do for my own jobs.   Do these steps have dependancies on each other?

Also, just out of curiosity, which schedulers/resource managers can queue multiple jobs within a loop in a submission script?   Not the PBS-based ones...

Comment: Torque has "job arrays". Very(!) neat
http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs/2.1jobsubmission.shtml